# Understanding initialization safety

Tags: java, multithreading

B. Goetz in his JCIP in chapter 16.3 wrote this:

> Initialization safety means that `SafeStates` in Listing 16.8 could be
>   safely published even through unsafe lazy initialization or stashing a
>   reference to a `SafeStates` in a public static field with no
>   synchroniation [...]

Code:

```
@ThreadSafe
public class SafeStates {
    private final Map<String, String> states;

    public SafeStates(){
        states = new HashMap<String, String>();
        states.put("alaska", "AK");
        states.put("alabama", "AL");
        ...
        states.put("wyoming", "WY");
    }

    public String getAbbreviation(String s){
        return states.fet(s);
    }
}
```

unsafe lazy initialization

```
@NotThreadSafe
public class UnsafeLazyInitialization{ 
    private static Resource resource;

    public static Resource getInstance(){
        if(resource == null)
            resource = new Resource();
        return resource;
    }
}
```

I don't understand why it is safe to publish object that way. The `resource` reference is not `volatile`, thus there's no `happens-before` between writing to it ( `resource = new Resource()` ) and subsequent readings from it even if `Resource` is immutable.

That way, any thread that did not initialize `resource` might observe **a stale value** of the `resource`.

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe he is referring to the fact that `SafeStates` has no mutators post-construction, so it doesn't really matter whether you have instance `a` or instance `b` - they're functionally identical. As such, you don't need synchronization (as it is logically immutable), and you don't need to worry about the lazily-initialized field having a stale value, as creating it again isn't really a problem.

Comment: @AndyTurner But I'm mostly concerned about the Unsafe lazy intialization. To be sure that any thread observes the most up-to-date value, do we have to declare it volatile?

Comment: You can, but my point is that "up to date" doesn't matter if two instances are entirely interchangable. An example of this is in `java.lang.String`'s [`hashCode` method](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/String.java#String.hashCode%28%29): it computes the result lazily and caches the value, but doesn't declare the cached value as `volatile` or anything like that: it's cheaper to occasionally recompute the value than to insist upon an up-to-date value.

Comment: @AndyTurner Ah, now I think I see the point... Even if some thread has already intialized the reference and another thread observed `null` there's going to be no data-corruption even if we initialize it one more. Since as you pointed out all instance are interchargable. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, exactly that.

Comment: But don't forget, the `Resource` must have final fields or expect that non-final fields could be not initialised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding this question right, it's not about why is the `@NotThreadSafe` example unsafe or why is the `@ThreadSafe` example safe.

It's about why is the combination of the two safe, i.e. why would the following be safe:

```
public class UnsafeLazyInitialization{ 
    private static SafeStates safeStates;

    public static SafeStates getInstance(){
        if (safeStates == null)
            safeStates = new SafeStates();
        return safeStates;
    }
}
```

The answer is that there is a "freezing action" at the end of the constructor, if a single `final` field is being initialized. That action (you can imagine it as a `StoreStore` barrier) ensures that if you see non-`null` instance, that instance will be fully initialized. Keep in mind though that this doesn't mean that you can't observe a `null` instance (the instance read is still racy).

For more info check this awesome blogpost by Aleksey Shipilev: [Safe Publication and Safe Initialization in Java](http://shipilev.net/blog/2014/safe-public-construction/#_safe_initialization).

Comment: Hm, good point. However, even so it doesn't look right. The code first initialises `states` final field, which is ok, but the fills the map after it. I doubt that it has guarantees that another thread will see fully filled map.

Comment: In practice, you will see the map at least as filled in the constructor, for exactly the same reasons that make the first example `@ThreadSafe`. There are caveats (e.g. within the `SafeStates` constructor you shouldn't leak `this` or the `states` instance to other threads), but the guarantee is practically there. That's explained both in JCiP and in the blogpost I've linked.

Comment: The SafeStates is thread safe, as the field is final, yes, but you are not paying attention that the HashMap is not! According to [JLS sec 17.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5) code example it may be a problem.

Comment: Could you give an example of the problem you're speaking about? And why would it not apply to the `@ThreadSafe` example from JCiP? The fact that `HashMap` is not thread safe is irrelevant here - initialization safety is not violated by this fact. Quoting JCiP: *Initialization safety means that `SafeStates` in Listing 16.8 could be safely published even through unsafe lazy initialization or stashing a reference to a `SafeStates` in a public static ﬁeld with no synchronization, even though it uses no synchronization and relies on the non-thread-safe `HashSet`* <sic>

Comment: Oh, I think the main point here is _Initialization safety makes visibility guarantees only for the **values that are reachable through final fields** as of the time the constructor finishes_, so the HashMap is a such value, that's why it is correct code. That makes sense.

Comment: I'm glad that we are on the same page now :) IMHO, safe publication and safe initialization are a little trickier than the other Java synchronization patterns. The current HotSpot and OpenJDK implementations actually provide visibility guarantees for all initialized fields if there's even a single `final` field, but that's an implementation detail.

Answer (score 2):

The UnsafeLazyInitialization is unsafe because one thread may set value of the `resource` before constructor of `Resource` is fully completed, so another thread will pick a reference to a partly initialised object.

Comment: Really? Surely the assignment to `resource` will only happen once `new Resource()` completes successfully?

Comment: @AndyTurner It looks like in code, but because there is no `happens-before` relation in the code, byte code or machine instructions could be reordered, so that observable behaviour from single thread point of view will be as you expect, but no guarantee the behaviour stays the same if you have access data from multiple threads.

Comment: so why is it safe to use an instance of `SafeStates` with the unsafe lazy initialization? The assignment of the final field happens-before the constructor returns, but does that mean the constructor returning happens-before the assignment?

Comment: @AndyTurner This is more interesting question. Because initialising a `final` field in Java5+ creates a happens-before relation. If you remove `final` or use older Java the code will become unsafe! See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5

Comment: Adding for my own benefit, this is described in [JLS sec 17.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5): "An object is considered to be completely initialized when its constructor finishes. A thread that can only see a reference to an object after that object has been completely initialized is guaranteed to see the correctly initialized values for that object's final fields.".

Answer (score -2):

The difference is that there is **"static"** in the unsafe code.
The static means the "resource" object is **class** object, not **instance** object.